# pymysql connection.cursor() in cycle is not receiving new rows

Tags: python, cursor, pymysql

```
mysql = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306,
    user=user, passwd=passwd, db=db, charset='utf8')
try:
    while True:
        with mysql.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("SELECT `data` FROM `tbl`")
            rows = cursor.fetchall()
        print(rows)
        print('Selected %d rows' % len(rows))
        # ... work with rows
        time.sleep(10)
finally:
    mysql.close()
```

Suppose in the table was 0 rows at the time of start of this code. Then, already in the process, I outside (phpmyadmin) add a few lines. But this code is still prints that no new rows (selected 0). But if the connection and closing placed inside the loop (at each iteration will be reconnecting), select will return a new row.

Why is that? How to fix that within a single connection pymysql seen all the changes?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. If you include `autocommit=True` in your connection parameters, the query results are new instead of what seems to be cached. This is more elegant than opening and closing for every query.

```
mysql = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306,
    user=user, passwd=passwd, db=db, charset='utf8', autocommit=True)
```